# Integrability in relation to taylor series

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be differentiable $n$ times in $a \in R$ and assume that $f$ is integrable at $[a-h,a+h]$ for $h> 0$. F is antiderivative of $f$ in that interval. Show that $\int _{a}^{x} T_n f(t) dt = T_{n+1} F(x) - F(a)$.

I know that the antiderivative of a polynomial $p(x) = \sum a_i x^i$ is 
$P(x) = \sum {a_i \over {i + 1}} x^i$.
and that if f is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then
$ \int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a) $.

How do I continue? Can someone help me please?

$T_n$ is a taylor series notation

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your $T_n$?

Comment: Editing it's a taylor series

Comment: What are the limits of the integration? (I suspect the answer is either that the lower limit is $a$ and the upper limit is $x$, and that moreover $F(x)$ is the *particular* antiderivative $\int_a^x f(y) dy$.)

Comment: right edited again

Comment: I think you should be able to do everything explicitly: explicitly calculate $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y) dy,T_n f(x),T_{n+1} F(x)$, and compare.